# Read Cookie Java Struts2

Tags: java, cookies, struts2

I am reading cookie values using struts code but it's not returning correct value as it contains `"=="`. For example, my cookie value `"Hw=="` reads as "Hw". Seems `==` is not a special character in the cookie spec but it still gives issues.

My code is below:

```
public static String getCookie(HttpServletRequest request, String name) {
    String value = null;

    for (Cookie c : request.getCookies()) {
        if (c.getName().equals(name)) {
            value = c.getValue();
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please make sure there is no white space in it

Comment: What container do you use? Looks like a bug related to given implementation.

Comment: What are the issues you are talking about? Please specify the errors.